# Symfony 2 Exception: Call to a member function on a non object when using Form Events

Tags: forms, events, exception, symfony, doctrine-orm

I'm trying to create a form which dinamically load all "sites" related to a "project", It seems like [this](http://symfony.com/doc/2.3/cookbook/form/dynamic_form_modification.html#cookbook-form-events-submitted-data) would be of use, so I tried it:

```
use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolverInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormEvent;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormEvents;

class EngineeringType extends AbstractType
{
        /**
     * @param FormBuilderInterface $builder
     * @param array $options
     */
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('project','entity',array(
                'class' => 'tBundle:Project',
                'label' => 'Project'
            ;
    $builder->addEventListener(
            FormEvents::PRE_SET_DATA,
            function(FormEvent $event) {
                $form = $event->getForm();
                $data = $event->getData();

                $sites = $data->getProject()->getSites();

                $form->add('site', 'entity', array('choices' => $sites));
            }
        );
    }
```

My problem comes when I try to access the form, I get:

```
FatalErrorException: Error: Call to a member function getSites() on a non-object in ... tBundle\Form\EngineeringType.php line 41
```

Here are my entities:

```
namespace tBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * Engineering
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="engineerings")
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
class Engineering
{
    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */

    private $id;

    /**
      * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="tBundle\Entity\Project")
      * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="project_id", referencedColumnName="id",nullable=false)
      */
    private $project;

    /**
     * Get id
     *
     * @return integer 
     */
    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    /**
     * Set project
     *
     * @param string $project
     * @return Engineering
     */
    public function setProject(\tBundle\Entity\Project $project)
    {
        $this->project = $project;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get project
     *
     * @return string 
     */
    public function getProject()
    {
        return $this->project;
    }
```

Project:

namespace tBundle\Entity;

```
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;

/**
 * Project
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="projects")
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
class Project
{
    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="name", type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $name;


     /**
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="tBundle\Entity\Site")
     * @ORM\JoinTable(name="project_sites",
     *      joinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="site_id", referencedColumnName="id")},
     *      inverseJoinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="project_id", referencedColumnName="id")}
     *      )
     */
    private $sites;

        public function __construct()
    {
        $this->sites = new ArrayCollection();
    }

    /**
     * Get id
     *
     * @return integer 
     */
    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    /**
     * Set name
     *
     * @param string $name
     * @return Project
     */
    public function setName($name)
    {
        $this->name = $name;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get name
     *
     * @return string 
     */
    public function getName()
    {
        return $this->name;
    }

    /**
     * Get Sites
     *
     * @return array 
     */
    public function getSites()
    {
        return $this->sites;
    }

    /* Returns Project's Name */
    public function __toString() 
    {
        return $this->name;
    }
```

What am I doing wrong?

**EDIT**

Controller:

```
/**
    * Creates a form to create a Engineering entity.
    *
    * @param Engineering $entity The entity
    *
    * @return \Symfony\Component\Form\Form The form
    */
    private function createCreateForm(Engineering $entity)
    {
        $form = $this->createForm(new EngineeringType(), $entity, array(
            'action' => $this->generateUrl('engineering_create'),
            'method' => 'POST',
        ));

        $form->add('submit', 'submit', array('label' => 'Create'));

        return $form;
    }


 /**
    * Creates a form to edit a Engineering entity.
    *
    * @param Engineering $entity The entity
    *
    * @return \Symfony\Component\Form\Form The form
    */
    private function createEditForm(Engineering $entity)
    {
        $form = $this->createForm(new EngineeringType(), $entity, array(
            'action' => $this->generateUrl('engineering_update', array('id' => $entity->getId())),
            'method' => 'POST',
        ));

        $form->add('submit', 'submit', array('label' => 'Update'));

        return $form;
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The PRE_SET_DATA event is actually fired twice.  The first time will not have any data.  There used to be a blurb in the manual explaining why but I could not find it again.

So just:

```
        function(FormEvent $event) {
            $form = $event->getForm();
            $data = $event->getData();
            if ($data)
            {

                $sites = $data->getProject()->getSites();

                $form->add('site', 'entity', array('choices' => $sites));
            }
        }
```

=======================================================

Updated answer to show how to handle non-existent $project:

```
            if ($data)
            {
                $project = $data->getProject();
                $sites = $project ? $project->getSites() : array();

                $form->add('site', 'entity', array('choices' => $sites));
            }
```

Comment: Hi! Thanks for answering. Tried this, but it seems although it's not null, it still get null values inside the entity. object(tBundle\Entity\Engineering)#285 (8) { [id":"tBundle\Entity\Engineering":private]=> NULL ["project":"tBundle\Entity\Engineering":private]=> NULL } (and other fields omitted intentionally)

Comment: That would be a different issue.  Maybe show some controller code where the engineering entity is passed to the form type.

Comment: How are you getting the engineering entity?  Does $entity->getProject() return a project?

Comment: I'm getting pretty much the same as the first comment. How should I get the entity? If it's a "new" entity. It only works on "edit"

Comment: You need to add a project if it's a brand new entity.  Otherwise getProject will of course fail.

Comment: I can't add a project. Otherwise It'd be pre set in the form on creation or that's the idea? The only thing I need, is the user to select a project on creation and the "sites" field filling with all the sites related to that project, if the project changes, the site list also changes.

Comment: Ok.  So in your listener check to see if you have a project.  If not then have $sites be an empty array.  See updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

There is an easy solution, why don't you use the "property" property on the form builder?

```
$builder
        ->add('project','entity',array(
            'class' => 'tBundle:Project',
            'label' => 'Project',
            'property' => 'sites');
```

Or even you can use a query builder if this is not enough:

```
$builder->add('users', 'entity', array(
    'class' => 'AcmeHelloBundle:User',
    'query_builder' => function(EntityRepository $er) {
        return $er->createQueryBuilder('u')
            ->orderBy('u.username', 'ASC');
    },
));
```

You can find here more description, if this is not enough:
[Symfony documentation](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/entity.html)

EDIT:

So your problem that with the first solution, that it's going to be an array, so use my second option, and in the query builder, specify what will reflect your needs.
Or use it like the class is not Project but Sites.

Comment: I tried your first solution, since it returns an array, it throws the error that can't be converted to string. If I'm able to populate another field with the results of that selected option in the field "project" then that'll do it